# Centos unable to upload file permission denied error

Tags: linux, ftp, centos

Yesterday I installed vsftpd in my centos server. But I am not able to upload files permission denied error. So I set owner and 775 file permission, and also i set 777 permission and then also I cant able to upload the file.

Here I am sending the link which i have followed.

http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=ftp

Please anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Lets see the ownership and permissions of the file you uploaded while having 777 on your directory

Comment: please see this


drwxrwxrwx. 2 temp1 tempftp 4096 May 20 17:33 temp

user : temp1
group: tempftp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user has write permission to the directory where file is going to be saved.

We have seen that user create files as the temp1 user, so one solution could be to make temp1 own the destination directory.

If that is impractical, an other solution could be to use group membership, either by chgrp'ing destination to tempftp or by adding user temp1 to the group that actually owns the destination.